# java bounded generic type definition

Tags: java, generics

What's the difference between the following type definitions

```
<E extends Number>
```

and

```
<? extends Number>
```

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 22):

This version:

```
<? extends Number>
```

can appear in a non-generic method/type, and it basically means "I don't care what the type is, so long as it derives from `Number`. I'm not going to really use the type, I just need it to be appropriate."

This version:

```
<E extends Number>
```

requires E to be a type parameter. It allows you to do more (for instance, creating an `ArrayList<E>` later on) but the extra type parameter can make things more complicated when you don't really need them to be.

Comment: More formally, would it be true to say that the second one is a formal type parameter definition, whereas the first is simply a parameter definiton?

Comment: Would it be true to say that you should use the second definition only when you need to refer to the type (via the 'alias' E)?

Comment: I wouldn't like to say on the first comment without consulting the spec (and I'm off to bed in a minute). The second comment seems reasonable though. Check what Josh Bloch has to say in Effective Java - he probably covers it :)

Comment: Actually, the question occurred to me while reading Effective Java!